# How to get value of property in javascript object?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-objects

I have an object which has `status` property. But I can't get the value of this property. Here is my code sample:

```
console.log("Resource.query()");
console.log(Resource.query());
console.log("Resource.query().status");
console.log(Resource.query().status);
```

Here is Chrome console:
[image]

As you see `Resource.query().status` returns `undefined` while `Resource.query()` returns the object. My question is how can I get the value of `status` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Resource.query().e.status` perhaps?

Comment: nope :( it returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`

Comment: Maybe (Resource.query()).e.status ?

Comment: How do you obtain this object? It might an issue with it being created asynchronously. Quick test - do: `setTimeout(function () {console.log(Resource.query().status);}, 2000);` and see if that shows the status after 2 seconds.

Comment: no ( the same error : `Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`

Comment: it returns undefined after 2 seconds too. what can I do ? (

Comment: I get the object from REST API using the angular.js's $resource service

Comment: @Miszy is probably on the right track, but with a bad test.  You want to check the status *property* (not an element) two seconds after running `Resource.query()`.

Comment: @Dennis, I did something like this: `setTimeout(function () {console.log(Resource.query());}, 2000);` it returns the same object again. no problem with object but element.

Comment: When you console.log an object, it will be updated if it changes.  Serialize it to get a snapshot:  `JSON.stringify(Resource.query())`.  Though a jsFiddle would be much more helpful.

Comment: JSON.stringify returns `{}`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query()` is run asynchronously as noted in the [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11) (emphasis added):

```
$scope.phones = Phone.query();
```

> > This is a simple statement that we want to query for all phones.  An important thing to notice in the code above is that we don't pass any callback functions when invoking methods of our Phone service. *Although it looks as if the result were returned synchronously, that is not the case at all.* What is returned synchronously is a "future" — an object, which will be filled with data when the XHR response returns. Because of the data-binding in Angular, we can use this future and bind it to our template. Then, when the data arrives, the view will automatically update.

Comment: Just bind the values into view.  View will update whenever query finishes.

Comment: The web doesn't work synchronously.  You can provide a function to `query` which will be called when the request completes, but you still need to wait for the REST call to be made.

Answer (score 0):

try this: 
`Resource.query()[0].status`